# Pegar coluna da tabela HTML

Tags: javascript, table

Pesquisei aqui no SOpt, mas não achei essa pergunta...

Como pegar todos valores de uma coluna no HTML? Só achei como pegar valor de uma célula, a idéia é depois fazer um filtro com os mesmos

Atualmente eu uso uma classe nas `<td>`, porém gostaria de algo que não precisasse adicionar uma classe pra cada linha, com JavaScript puro, sem JQuery ou algo do gênero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode percorrer todas as células da coluna com o seletor `document.body.querySelectorAll("table th:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(2)")`, e ir pegando os textos da coluna que você indicar em `nth-child()`. No exemplo abaixo, estou pegando a segunda coluna (`nth-child(2)`). Usei também o método `.trim()` para excluir espaços vazios nas extremidades dos textos das células:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   var tabela = document.body.querySelectorAll("table th:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(2)");
   
   for(var x=0; x<tabela.length; x++){
      console.log(tabela[x].textContent.trim());
   }
   
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
   <th>
      th1
   </th>
   <th>
      th2
   </th>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            coluna 1 linha1
         </td>
         <td>
            coluna 2 linha1
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            coluna 1 linha2
         </td>
         <td>
           coluna 2 linha2
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```